# Get the name of the list object then add that name as a new column of the each list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes.  Then I want to extract the list object name and add that as the first column in the dataframe.  THen I want to unlist the and make a single dataframe combining each dataframe by row.  They all have the same dimensions.

A small section of my list of dataframes below

```
mylist <- list(SiO2 = structure(c(5.121, 0.00836394378003293, 0.0199499373432604, 
5, 10, 1.87883863763252, 0.0836503954062112, 2.1240292640167), .Dim = c(1L, 
8L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Analyte_Mean", "SDBetweenGroup", 
"SDWithinGroup", "replicates", "NumSamples", "FValue", "PValue", 
"FCritical"))), Al2O3 = structure(c(2.0812, 0.0053103672189408, 
0.0159059737205869, 5, 10, 0.442687747035557, 0.903289230024797, 
2.1240292640167), .Dim = c(1L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Analyte_Mean", 
"SDBetweenGroup", "SDWithinGroup", "replicates", "NumSamples", 
"FValue", "PValue", "FCritical"))))
```

I have the following to get the name of the list object names. But unsure how to pass it back as a column for each dataframe

```
names(mylist)
```

to make a single dataframe I have

```
new_list <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, mylist))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, I'd probably use the `purrr` library.  `imap_dfr` will pass both your matrix and its name to the function, and then bind the results into a single dataframe.

```
library(purrr)

new_list <- imap_dfr(mylist, function(mat, name) {
  result <- as.data.frame(mat)
  result$name <- name
  result
})
```

gives

```
> new_list
  Analyte_Mean SDBetweenGroup SDWithinGroup replicates NumSamples    FValue    PValue FCritical  name
1       5.1210    0.008363944    0.01994994          5         10 1.8788386 0.0836504  2.124029  SiO2
2       2.0812    0.005310367    0.01590597          5         10 0.4426877 0.9032892  2.124029 Al2O3
```

Comment: thanks your solution worked as well.  If I could vote for both solutions I would.  Ronak Solution produced a slightly better final result by having the names as the first column.

Comment: No worries.  Though there's no rule against upvoting multiple answers.  You can only accept one answer - which you should definitely also do for Ronak's answer if it works best for you - but upvoting and accepting are two different things.  Unless it's a rep thing?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `purrr::map_df` -

```
purrr::map_df(mylist, data.frame, .id = 'name')

#   name Analyte_Mean SDBetweenGroup SDWithinGroup replicates NumSamples
#1  SiO2       5.1210    0.008363944    0.01994994          5         10
#2 Al2O3       2.0812    0.005310367    0.01590597          5         10

#     FValue    PValue FCritical
#1 1.8788386 0.0836504  2.124029
#2 0.4426877 0.9032892  2.124029
```

Or in base R -

```
do.call(rbind, Map(cbind.data.frame, mylist, name = names(mylist)))
```

Comment: your purr solution worked best as it added the a new column with the names, whilst the base R solution created row names instead of adding a new column

Comment: @Spooked Look at the last column, there is a column called `name` at the end. It also creates rownames here. If you want `name` to be first column use `do.call(rbind, Map(cbind.data.frame, name = names(mylist), mylist))`

Answer (score 1):

`bind_rows()` will automatically create an "ID" column with the argument `id = "your_column_name"`.